# Изменение вида ошибки в django 2.1.2

Tags: django

Стандартный вид ошибок Django очень не очень, поэтому я решил изменить их вид. Используя curry вылазит ошибка:

```
    handler403 = curry(permission_denied, template_name='errs/403.html'),
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вот так выглядит стандартная ошибка:[image: вот обычная ошибка]

Есть ли другие способы, или у меня проблемы с curry?

Comment: SyntaxError не имеет никакого отношения к каким-либо curry, вы просто где-то написали некорректный код

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто завести шаблоны вида `<http-код>.html`. Например 403.html, 404.html и 500.html Когда `DEBUG = False` они будут автоматически использоваться при возникновении соответствующих ошибок.

[Соответствующий раздел документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/views/#error-views).

Comment: Не помогло. Выводится как и было

Comment: Это странно. У меня работает.